# Click Listeners for onStartIconClickListeners not working in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, data-binding

I am implementing onstartIconClickletener using a custom attribute and Binder method

My Layout element is

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text.layout.email.and.phone"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:hint="@string/txt_email_phone"
                android:textColorHint="@color/bg_input_text"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/bg_input_text"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/bg_input_text"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
                app:prefixTextColor="@color/text_color_white_1"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_down_arrow"
                app:startIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:onStartIconClicked = "@{(view)->viewModel.onStartIconClicked(view)}"
                app:prefixText="@{viewModel.prefixText}">
```

I created an interface with one single method

```
public interface StartInconOnClickListener {
    void onStartIconClicked(View view);
}
```

In my BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:onStartIconClicked"}) 
public static void setonStartIconClickedListener(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, StartInconOnClickListener newListener) { 
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
            newListener.onStartIconClicked(v); 
        } 
    }; 
    textInputLayout.setStartIconOnClickListener(onClickListener); 
}
```

But clicking the startIcon it is invoking onClick in the BindingAdapter, but it is not calling my lambda function in the ViewModel

My Lamda function in the view model is

```
public void onStartIconClicked(View view) {
        prefixText.set("+91");
        Event event = new Event(Boolean.valueOf(true));
        _showCountryCodeDialog.setValue(event);
    }
```

I spent the whole day. now I am looking for help

Answer (score 0):

Please dont respond to this question, it is mistake since the viewmodel object in the layout was null.

How we can see these issues when a null pointer exception is happening in the layout file